# How do you deploy a next.js app using SWA-CLI (for Azure Static Apps)

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app

SWA-CLI
https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/

I created a basic next js app on my machine using

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

After installing the SWA-cli, I run

```
swa init
```

I enter my configuration name when prompted.  It shows me the following detected configuration for my app.

```
Detected configuration for your app:
- Framework(s): React, Next.js
- App location: .
- Output location: .
- API location:
- App build command: npm run build
- API build command:
- App dev server command: npm dev
- App dev server URL: http://localhost:3000

? Are these settings correct? › (Y/n)
```

I say Yes

Then I run

```
swa build
```

This will build my project and give me the following output

```
Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.0.2)

Using configuration "my-next-app" from file:
  /Users/bob/workspace/my-next-app/swa-cli.config.json

Build configuration:
- App location: .
- API location:
- Output location: .
- App build command: npm run build
- API build command:
Found package.json in .
Installing dependencies with "npm install"...

up to date, audited 229 packages in 757ms

77 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Building app with npm run build in . ...

> my-next-app@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /Users/bob/workspace/my-next-app/.env
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      5.35 kB        83.4 kB
├   └ css/ae0e3e027412e072.css             707 B
├   /_app                                  0 B              78 kB
├ ○ /404                                   182 B          78.2 kB
└ λ /api/hello                             0 B              78 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              78.3 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-09a2284fdc01dc36.js   45.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-017a64f48d901a37.js        31.2 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-620102ba3a9296b8.js  497 B
  ├ chunks/webpack-cc9c69bc14c8e1bc.js     750 B
  └ css/ab44ce7add5c3d11.css               247 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Then I run

```
swa deploy
```

I select the subscription in my Azure account when prompted.
I then select the Azure Static App in the portal within that subscription when prompted

This is the error I get

```
Checking project settings...
✔ Choose your Static Web App › Test-SWA/Test-SWA
✔ Successfully setup project!

Deploying to environment: preview

Deploying project to Azure Static Web Apps...
✖ Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (/). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
✖ If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 'app_location' in your deployment configuration file points to the root of your application.
✖ If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists in the build output directory.
```

I am new to next.js
Now I understand that it cant find index.html, but that is because it does not exist.  Since this is all js it will all get rendered when the project is being run.  So I think the issue is that my configuration is incorrect when i run 'swa init' but because of my knowledge gaps of next.js I cannot figure out the right configuration.  I have gotten this to work for a normal react app since that contains the index.html file.

Comment: Refer [Build Configurations for Azure Static WebApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#build-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/nextjs

Deployment via the SWA CLI is unsupported in preview.

Curious if you were able to get it working.

Comment: Not with next.js