# SWA cli emulator crashes when enabling SSL with NextJS dev server

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app

I try to run NextJS development server with SWA emulator. After enabling SSL, emulator crashes after first request. If I do static export of the NextJS site and use that folder with emulator, everything works correctly.

Any ideas what could go wrong? I have tried older versions of SWA Cli + disabled NVM and installed NodeJS directly.

Everything is also described here: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues/741

swa-cli.config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    "new-swa-test": {
      "appLocation": ".",
      "outputLocation": ".next",
      "appBuildCommand": "npm run build",
      "run": "npm run dev",
      "appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:3001",
      "ssl": true,
      "verbose": "silly"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Output after 'swa start' (certification details snipped away)

[swa] node "C:\Users\heinonenjj\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.14.0\node_modules@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 0
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[run] cd "C:\code\swa-test\new-swa-test" && npm run dev exited with code 1
✖ SWA emulator stoped because the --run command exited with code 1.

Comment: Hope this reference helps [DOC1](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/cli/swa-init) , [DOC2](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/use/emulator/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666601/how-do-you-deploy-a-next-js-app-using-swa-cli-for-azure-static-apps)

Comment: git [issues](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28114)

Comment: [deploy](https://dev.to/azure/deploy-next-js-with-azure-static-web-app-service-and-github-actions-32j0)

Answer (score 0):

- I am  able to run by setting `"SSL":  true`
- Created a `Next JS` with the command
  `npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog`
- I have used the   [MSDOC](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup) reference  to setup `Next JS`

`npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog`

- Make sure to build the application `npm run build` and added , local SSL with   [Next.js](https://waltergalvao.dev/how-to-set-up-local-ssl-with-nextjs)  and [git](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935).
- create local-server.js
- To create a SWA Cli in the next js application use `swa init`

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Use Next.js over HTTPS instead of HTTP   [vercel/next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935)

```json
{

"$schema":  "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",

"configurations":  {

"nextjs-blog":  {

"appLocation":  ".",

"outputLocation":  ".next",

"appBuildCommand":  "npm run build",

"run":  "npm run dev",

"appDevserverUrl":  "http://localhost:3000",
"ssl":  true
}
}
}
```

used `swa start` to run

- Deployed the app with `swa deploy`

[image]

**Local Output:**
[image]

**Azure :**

[image]

- For more details reference  [SSL](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+enable+ssl+in+windows+11&docid=603543759546825079&mid=421CB857A8EBE29A3B45421CB857A8EBE29A3B45&view=detail&FORM=VIRE) with NextJS dev [server](https://windowsreport.com/ssl-cipher-mismatch-browser-error/)  and  [git](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues/741) .